# Dart Null Safety in a callback function with named params

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

The code below fails when compiling with Null Safety the following error:

**The parameter `namedParam` can't have a value of `null` because of its type, and no non-null default value is provided**.

```
void main() {
  Foo(callbackWithNamedParam: ({namedParam}) { 
    print('param=$namedParam');
  }).callback();
}

class Foo {
  final void Function({required int namedParam}) callbackWithNamedParam;
  
  Foo({required this.callbackWithNamedParam});
  
  void callback() {
    callbackWithNamedParam(namedParam: 10);
  }
}
```

When compiling without Null Safety the code compiles perfectly well.

[DartPad](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/a4fe1d58517c28869876862cae4acbcb) **with** Null Safety that fails compiling

[DartPad](https://www.dartpad.dev/f210b3e0b0cb6546329cdb9c85aa2285) **without**  Null Safety that compiles well

Is there a way to fix it:

1. Without switching to positional parameter
   AND
2. Without making the named parameter `nullable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your named param `int?`.  It will then accept either an int or null:

```
final void Function({int? namedParam}) callbackWithNamedParam;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with nullable named parameter but I don't want to make it nullable. I clarified the question.

Comment: Well. I totally missed it. I need to add `required` to the anonymous function as well. Thank you for making me recheck my code.

Comment: Can you please clarify both cases (nullable and non-nullable) parameters for the sake of completeness of the answer for other developers to come? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on [Randal'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865110/396949)s answer. From [Dart's documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters)

[image]

So in order to resolve my issue, I had to add `required` to the anonymous function

```
Foo(callbackWithNamedParam: ({required namedParam}) { 
                              ^^^^^^^^
    print('param=$namedParam');
  }).callback();
```

My working code can be found in this [Dartpad](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/641d14e5b0d1119779370384e38ecf8e)